# What is wrong with "Why is there such a dislike for the Alien Prequels?" and why was it closed

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

Recently I asked a question on here:

[Why is there such a dislike for the Alien Prequels?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224747/why-is-there-such-a-dislike-for-the-alien-prequels/224749#224749)

It was not well received. What is the issue with it? I mean, most discussions involving films will be opinion-based on some sort of level.  I feel like the magnitude of negativity was not exactly fair.

Comment: Cf. [What was the general critical reaction to Star Trek: The Motion Picture?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/108486/31394) and [Why do so many Trekkies hate Star Trek Into Darkness?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/139020/31394)

Answer (score 6):

The close message explains why: you're asking for opinions. Asking for opinions is a bad idea for a question *here*, since there is no way to determine the correct answer — there is none.

That doesn't mean you can't ask why a work wasn't received better. Examples of well-received similar questions are

- [Why didn't The Thing (1982) fare better at the box office?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/101948/19561)
- [What was the general critical reaction to Star Trek: The Motion Picture?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/108486/19561)

If you edit your question to focus more on how it was received by critics and the general public, I would vote for it to be reopened.

Answer (score -1):

*Specifically to the point:* Stack Exchange is [not a discussion forum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour). Says so right in the Tour: it's a place for getting specific answers to focused questions. Most questions that begin with "why" are asking for opinions and are going to be closed for being opinion based, for being too broad or lacking focus.

The [Help Center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) has lots of resources that show you how to formulate good queries and also address what kinds of queries to avoid asking.